# Git for Windows is creating commits with duplicate dates to the one before it?

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-commit, git-gui

I use Git for Windows and the GUI that comes along with it, and when I create a new commit either in Git Bash or Git GUI, it's creating new commits with the same date as the one before it.

[image: Git GUI showing duplicate dates created]

I have no idea why it's doing this. I've gotten most of the commits I needed done tonight, but I don't want all my commits to be stuck on November 13th!

A week later (11/20) and I am still able to reproduce this issue. These are my global Git variables:

```
MINGW64 /d/Users/Public/Music/Playlists (master)
$ echo ${!GIT_*}
GIT_EXEC_PATH

MINGW64 /d/Users/Public/Music/Playlists (master)
$ echo $GIT_EXEC_PATH
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core
```

Comment: The next time you do or are about to do a commit in git bash, do `echo ${!GIT_*}`, that will show if the names of any git overrides hanging around somehow.  This behavior you're describing here is not normal.  The only thing I can think of so far is you've somehow got `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` set and exported, perhaps you sourced a script rather than just running it?

Comment: @jthill I was playing with `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` on another repository where just like in your answer (sic?) I was fast-forwarding commits from another branch and they all got the same date, so I was trying to import them with the correct date. Actually, now that I'm looking at it that didn't work and set two of my 2015 commits in 2016: https://github.com/NobleUplift/BackToBack/commits/master

Comment: I'll try to fix the above issue when I get home, and I'll cry myself to sleep in a corner now that I have to try doing a `filter-branch` on BackToBack again.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are only doing `git commit` and not `git rebase`, right?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, `git commit`, though one of those was a `git commit --amend`, would that cause any issues?

Comment: `git commit --amend` will change the commit timestamp (as opposed to the authored timestamp) but if anything, that will make it even later and only for the single amended commit.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That's my intention with testing this. I'm just amending and re-committing in an attempt to fix it. So far, not even computer restarts have.

Comment: What happens when you create a brand new test repository along with a few empty commits? That should tell you whether it's a problem with your Git set-up, or with your repo.

Comment: Does your screenshot show the commit times or the authored times?

Comment: @hvd I just did that and was able to reproduce with an amended commit. When I amend commits, that commit and every future commit has the same timestamp as the amended commit.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice What's the difference? I'd venture to assume Commit Times. The interface is from [git-gui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui).

Comment: IIRC, the "authored times" is the timestamp for the original creation of the commit. The "commit time" is the timestamp that the commit was most recently changed. Commands like `git rebase` and `git commit --amend` can change the "commit time". (I might have these backwards, so I suggest you google them to verify.)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I stand corrected. It's showing the Author Date, not the Committer Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **Don't amend commits I guess.**

I know that I've amended commits without it affecting the next commit on other systems, i.e. Linux and OS X, but just to fix my current repository so I could keep using it, this is what I did:

```
Playlists2$ git checkout e71521b3b26c5e053fa7ce2f4e2ca602de9b734f
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ROBOCOPY Playlists2 Playlists1 /MIR /COPY:D /XD .git
Playlists1$ GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2016-11-13 19:47:27" GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2016-11-13 19:47:27" git commit -m "Massive UUID updates for entire directory, but restore last modified date\n\nROBOCOPY <backup> <cwd> /COPY:T /XD .git"

Playlists2$ git checkout 9ec2d7abfac0c1a1c5eaeb58abedcb65bbab29e5
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ROBOCOPY Playlists2 Playlists1 /MIR /COPY:D /XD .git
Playlists1$ GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2016-11-13 21:26:46" GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2016-11-13 21:26:46" git commit -m "Fix missing tracks and save dates before mass deleting playlists"

Playlists2$ git checkout fdea81464c9fff080249b5287693a4d0555fcc06
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ROBOCOPY Playlists2 Playlists1 /MIR /COPY:D /XD .git
Playlists1$ GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2016-11-13 22:11:51" GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2016-11-13 22:11:51" git commit -m "Remove unused playlists and collapse soundtracks into mega playlist"

Playlists2$ git checkout 0fe301fc61526944ae178d360b0482739e0dfefc
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ROBOCOPY Playlists2 Playlists1 /MIR /COPY:D /XD .git
Playlists1$ GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2016-11-13 22:18:34" GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2016-11-13 22:18:34" git commit -m "Remove interwoven, contemporary, duplicate, and missed playlists"

Playlists2$ git checkout 
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ROBOCOPY Playlists2 Playlists1 /MIR /COPY:D /XD .git
Playlists1$ GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2016-11-13 22:22:00" GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2016-11-13 22:22:00" git commit -m "Add new playlist for Aurora"
```

I restored an old version of my Playlists directory, renaming it Playlists1 (had to delete the desktop.ini that made the directory display as Playlists) with the current corrupted version Playlists2, checked out each commit from Playlists2, mirrored the data to Playlists1 excluding the .git folder, and made the commit with date overrides.

I'll play around with the test repository I created since there's a way to fix the Git repository so that it starts committing with the correct author date again (since the first 2 were duplicates and next three were duplicates), and I'll leave this question unaccepted until then.

Answer (score 3):

[Git takes rarely-used overrides from the environment](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#Committing), and the only thing I can think of that would produce the behavior you're describing here is if you've somehow left `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` set and exported.  Perhaps you sourced a script into your running shell?

Anyway, you can see the names of any current git overrides with `echo ${!GIT_*}.`unset` them if you find any, that should do it.

Comment: I was out late so I didn't turn my computer on last night. Better luck today.

Comment: I added the output of that echo to my question. Only `GIT_EXEC_PATH` is set.

Comment: And immediately after that, you do `git commit` from the command line, and the resulting commit doesn't have the system date?  Check the system's idea of the date, is this in a VM or something?  Something's very, very scwewy on your system.

Comment: I did a git commit --amend and recommitted, and I'm on a normal installation of Windows 10. I'll backup my repository and do a clean commit to see what the date on that is.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it! It happens when I `git commit --amend` and then re-commit, and continue committing. Every future commit has the timestamp of the amended commit. This seems like a bug in Git for Windows. Can I report it?

Comment: If you can show how to reproduce that, sure.  What's "re-commit" mean?  This isn't normal behavior, I don't expect it's just the command sequence, there's something weird in your setup.

Comment: By re-commit, I meant amended my commit. Amended commits causes my dates to corrupt.

Comment: @NobleUplift I'm seeing the same issue and I suspect it is indeed caused by amending commits. How did you fix it? I guess the dates are lost but were you able to get git to track real dates again in the same repository?